# What does the ++ operator do to an Integer?

Tags: java, variable-assignment, wrapper

Following test case will pass:

```
@Test
public void assignWrapperTest() {
    System.out.printf("\nassign - %s\n", "wrapper");

    Integer a = 1000;
    Integer b = a;
    System.out.printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
    Assert.assertEquals(a, b);
    Assert.assertSame(a, b); // a, b are the same object,

    a++;
    System.out.printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
    Assert.assertNotEquals(a, b);
    Assert.assertNotSame(a, b); // a, b are not the same object, any more,
}
```

So:

- `a` is changed by `++`.
- `b` remains the same.

**The questions are:**

- `b = a` just assign the reference value right, they refer to the same object, at this point there is only one object, right?
- What ++ operator does on an Integer?
  Since Integer is immutable, does this means `++` created a new Integer object, and assigned it back to the original variable automatically? If that's the case, does that means `a` now point to a different object?
- There are 2 objects now? And `b` still point to the original one ?

Comment: Yes, yes, and yes. You seem to understand this already.

Comment: @khelwood I am a bit confused at first, I just write a test case and try to figure it out, but I am not very sure is that the real case, so asked the question.

Comment: Your questions have the answers within them. And your intuition is right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
a++;
```

Because `a` is an `Integer`, this is the same as:

```
a = Integer.valueOf(a.intValue() + 1);
```

> does this means `++` created a new Integer object

Maybe, but not necessarily: [`Integer.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-) will reuse a cached value; a new value will only be created if outside the cached range (which is at least -128..127).

Comment: To add to this answer, if `a` is within that caching range (eg `123`), and you do `a++` *and* `b++` they will point to the same object.

Comment: So, the `++` operator is not atomic, since it has more than 1 operations, right?

Comment: @EricWang correct. It's not atomic for `int` either.

Comment: Ok, seems `++` on `Integer` need 4 individual steps, and on `int` need 2 steps roughly, anyhow, either are more than 1 step.

Comment: @EricWang the steps for `int` are read; add one; write.

Comment: Ok, so 3 steps for `++` on `int`.

Comment: "Integer.valueOf will reuse a cached value; a new value will only be created if outside the cached range (which is at least -128..127)." - no, even if a new value is created within the cached range it will be a new value, no caching. at least in Java 11

Comment: @AndreyM.Stepanov can you provide a code snippet to demonstrate that? The Java 11 docs [explicitly states](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)): "This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range."

Comment: @andy-turner well, if you simply run a = 120;
  b = a;
  System.out.printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
  a++;
  System.out.printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b); the result will be a = 120, b = 120; a = 121, b = 120. If I see it right no putting here to sort of Integer pool or cache.  Java 11.0.12

Comment: @AndreyM.Stepanov I think you are confused about what incrementing an `Integer` variable does: it doesn't change anything about the Integer instance the variable points to (nothing can, `Integer` is immutable. Can you imagine the mayhem if you could make 120 "equal to" 121?). `a++` is assigning a new value to `a`, as described in the answer; this does nothing to the value of the `b` variable.

Comment: @andy-turner then what is the meaning of the phrase ""Integer.valueOf will reuse a cached value; a new value will only be created if outside the cached range (which is at least -128..127)."?  Could you please provide an example. This cache probably means the same as string pool. Does it mean that if Integer a = 120, and Integer b =120 then a==b. But if Integer a = 130. and Integer b =130 then a != b (which looks like nonsense)

Comment: oh, no...   Integer a = 120;
  Integer b  = 120;

  boolean flag = a==b? true : false;

  a = 200;
  b  = 200;

   flag = a==b? true : false;
first result is true, second is false
it's RIDICULOUS

Answer (score 4):

If we look at the `Byte code` of `a++`; It looks something like below:

```
    9: aload_1
   10: invokevirtual #22                 // Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
   13: iconst_1
   14: iadd
   15: invokestatic  #16                 // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
   18: astore_1
```

So the instructions are like getting the `intValue()` of `a` then `increment` it then call `Integer#valueOf` on the incremented value and Integer#valueOf create a new object.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

**`Integer` objects are immutable. But, their references held by are mutable.**
`Integer` classes, cache data and reuse them.

Let's see what's happening in your code.

`Integer a = 1000;` // Let's say it creates a memory block of 4 bytes in heap with address reference `&addr_of_val_1000;`

`Integer b = a;` // now, b points to address reference `&addr_of_val_1000;`

`a++;` // this creates/fetches a new value `1001` in/from heap with new address reference `&addr_of_val_1001;` and assignes to variable a

So,

a = 1001 and b = 1000 are not equal.
&addr_of_val_1000 != &addr_of_val_1001 (their references are not same anymore)

But, if you add,

`b++;`

or

`b = Integer.valueOf(1001)`

before your check, they will be equal and same again.

Answer (score 1):

- That is correct. That is the way the JVM works.
- Yes. `a++` effectively does `a=a+1` (ignoring the logic to convert it to an `Integer`). The expression `a+1` evaluates to a new `int`, and that gets assigned to `a`.
- Affirmative. The value of `b` has not been touched by the previous operations, and hence it's still pointing at the same object.

Answer (score 1):

The key point here is that `Integer` is `immutable`.

1. If the operand is mutable, like an `int`, `++` operator just add `1` to the original value **in place**.
2. For `Integer` it is different. By `a++`, a new instance of `Integer` is created, and the value of it comes from adding a `1` to the original Integer object which both `a` and `b` are pointing to, and then `a` is re-assigned to this new object. `b` still refers to the original Integer object,  so `a` and `b` are not the same now.